# how to make the Fragment Refresh itself, from another activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

Every time I want to make my fragment call it's onStart() or onResume(), I do the the next :

```
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.containero1, new Massenger_frag(conversationID)).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

is this good for the performance, is there another way to tell the fragment the new information arrived, and it must refresh its UI.

Comment: What do you mean "from another activity"?  What is the point of refreshing a fragment of an activity the user cannot see?

Comment: the new information arraived to main activity, and I want the Fragment to "Know" about that, so I put the info in a variable and call the fragment to be visible, a in the code above, but when the fragment is visible and new info arrived to the main activity,I dont know how to refresh the fragment so I call it another time by the code above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a reference to a "Massenger_frag" object that was used when doing the fragment replacement. You can also define a method "refresh" in your "Massenger_frag" class and call it from that instance variable. onStart()/onResume() from your fragment would also call the same refresh method to avoid code duplication.

What you are currently doing is not fast and adds a significant overhead as the new fragment is constructed every time and the old one gets deallocated.

Answer (score 1):

the solution is simple: I just use BroadCast sender and receiver, and send the information throw Activity A to Activity B, the Activity B in its onReceive() call a function that refresh its content!

Answer (score 0):

Use [interface](https://www.google.com/search?q=java%20interface) and create custom EventListeners.  Check an example [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#Implement)